# ADS1278 double values

Tags: adc, serial, communication

I am recently using a [ADS1278](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1278.pdf) as the ADC of my system. The configuration is Frame-sync, TDM, Fixed for the 8 channels. The mode is high speed (sampling at 64KSPS). The core clock and the serial clock is the same at 16384000 Hz. The voltages and analog circuits follows the example circuit in the data sheet. So I am reading the data (input is a square wave for now), and all 8 channels seem to give reasonably correct values (at least in estimated voltage), the clock seems not too jittery and I can take the values to re-plot the square wave. However I noticed that all the values I read are repeated twice (always, and very consistently), for example, if I read 5 as my first value, the next value will be 5, and the two afterwards are the same value, and so on. I am not sure why that is the case. I did probe the data line vs the frame sync line which shows that two consecutive frame syncs worth of data gives the exact same value. I don't know why this is the case.

Comment: What are your mode and CLKDIV settings?  You may be pulsing fsync before the next conversion is available, so it just gives you the same data again.  How many clock cycles are you running per frame?

Comment: @caveman Sorry to mention, CLKDIV is hard wired to 3.3V as I am always using high speed mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry,

Just found out my mode was wrong, which put me in low speed mode and thus having a data to frame sync ratio of 512 instead of 256 and max of 52KSPS which gave me bad values. Changed it to high speed mode, and everything seems fine.

=)